# I've a problem in my vite + react project with fetching data with axiox , i'm using process.env + MY API KEY ,

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, vite, strapi

[and there's my snaps to console and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpTew.jpg)][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/efb3g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg0Op.png)

I'm trying to return the right data, but it runs with only a static API URL.
I've tried to fix my vite.config.js

`````
import { defineConfig , loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({mode})=> {
  process.env ={...process.env , ...loadEnv(mode , process.cwd())};
  return defineConfig({
    define :{
      'process.env' : JSON.stringify(process.env),
    },
    plugins: [react()],
  });
}````

but after this alsogote an error that said
`````

Comment: this my error , it must go to : localhost:1337/api/products to request the data but it go to 
my client-server on port : 5173 
GET http://localhost:5173/undefined/products?populate=* 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear specific question and not just state that you have a problem. We _all_ have problems. Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. Put all information in your question, not down here.

Comment: Also take the time to fix your post formatting. It's not difficult.